# Copy part of file in C++

Tags: c++, windows, fwrite, stdio, fread

I'm currently busy with a project in which I have to copy a part from a file to another file, so I made a code for that using fread and fwrite. But I came across a problem: for testing purposes I made a code which should copy a whole file, but somehow the code creates copies that are larger than the original file. See the code I made below

```
             FILE *base_file;
             FILE *new_file;
             fpos_t curpos;
             int tmp;

             // Open the base file
             fopen_s(&base_file, "C:/base.dat", "rb");
             // Open the file which should contain the copy
             fopen_s(&new_file, "C:/new.dat", "w");

             // Get the filesize
             fseek(base_file, 0, SEEK_END);
             fgetpos(base_file, &curpos);
             fseek(base_file, 0, SEEK_SET);

             //Read and copy (it seems to go wrong here)
             for(int i = 0; i < curpos; i++){
                 fread (&tmp, 1, 1, base_file);
                 fwrite(&tmp, 1, 1, new_file);
             }

             fclose(base_file);
             fclose(new_file);
```

The base file is 525 kb, and the newfile is 527kb. As far as I could see the parts where this problem occurs is after parts where there are 7 nullbytes, and the copy somehow has added a '0D'(in Hex) after these parts. In ascii the '0D' character is a 'carriage return'. I was wondering what could be the reason that my copy code adds carriage returns into the file? As far as I know this script should just work as I just read the basefile, and directly copy it to the newfile, and the basefile doesn't contain these carriage returns.

Comment: Added the Windows tag because this `fopen_s` seems to be an MS invention. Correct me if I'm wrong. You might want to open the second file in mode `wb`, btw.

Comment: @larsmans: It's the secure CRT function, but it's not really relevant to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're opening the destination file in text mode, instead of binary mode, so the newline translation happens behind your back. Change the mode to `"wb"`.

Other notes:

1. Use streams rather than stdio.
2. Don't write byte-for-byte. Use a larger buffer, your method will take forever for larger files.

Comment: Third note: don't use `fopen_s` if you're not checking the return value anyway. `fopen` is more portable and equally (in)secure when no error checking is done.

Comment: Well, yeah, that's covered by "don't use stdio at all". :P

Comment: It might sometimes be beneficial to use `stdio`. I'm not familiar with MSVC, but I have found that some `iostreams` implementations are still slower than `stdio`.

Comment: Thanks for all answers! Changing the mode to WB worked, but I will try to take your advice and change to streams instead of stdio.Also thanks for the tip about fopen_s. I also changed to usign a buffer mode, I used the byte-for-byte mode to easier find the problem.

Comment: @larsmans: You're doing I/O. The differences in implementation speed are negligible, especially for unformatted operations.

Comment: Hmm, yes, I guess for binary I/O the difference will be negligible. +1 btw.

Answer (score 2):

Will "wb" instead of "w" fix it?